# Django / Python: Sorting QuerySet by field on first instance of foreignkey relation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following 2 models, a `Lesson` model, that can have multiple start / end dates - each with their own `Date` model.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    (...)


class Date(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(
        Lesson,
        verbose_name="dates",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

For our project we need to order the `Lessons` by the `start_date` of their **earliest** `Date` instance.

So far example, if I have the following data:

```
MEETING A:
   DATE_1a: 2022-11-01 --> 2022-11-02
   DATE_2a: 2022-12-10 --> 2022-12-11

MEETING B:
   DATE_1b: 2022-11-03 --> 2022-11-04
   DATE_2b: 2022-11-05 --> 2022-11-06
```

Then the queryset should return `[<MEETING A>, <MEETING B>]` based on the `start_date` values of the `DATE_1a/b` instances. (`2022-11-01` is earlier than `2022-11-03`, al other Dates are ignored)

However, what I thought would be a relatively simply query has proven to be a rather evasive problem. My initial approach of the default `order_by` method used all `Date` instances attached to a `Meeting` (and worse, returned a separate `Meeting` result for each `Date` instance)

```
qs.order_by(F("dates__start_date").asc(nulls_first=True))
```

However -I could not conceive of a query to do what we need to happen. My current working solution is to use a whole bunch of python code to instead do:

```
ordered_meetings = []
meeting_dict = {}
for meeting in qs:
    first_date = meeting.dates.first()
    if not meeting_dict.get(meeting.id):
        meeting_dict[meeting.id] = first_date.start_date
```

And then ordering the dict based on its date values, using the ID/KEYS to fetch the `Meeting` instances and append them to the `ordered_meetings` list.

But this is such a convoluted (and much slower) approach that I feel that I must be missing something. Does anyone know a more succinct method of accomplishing what we want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you need a min?

Something like (untested):

```
Meeting.objects.annotate(first_date=Min('dates__start_date')).order_by('first_date')
```

Comment: I really need to read up on the use of annotations. Thanks for the assist, that did it!